# Better conditional lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I am producing a CSV file that contains 3 columns, with 2 extra optional columns. I have a function which stores each of the rows as a list inside a container list, which I later can iterate over and produce the csv.

```
import itertools as itt    

def csvContainer(col1, col2, col3, col4=None, col5=None):
    container = [
        [c1, c2, c3] for c1, c2, c3 in 
        itt.izip(col1, col2, col3)
        ]
    if col4:
        for row, c4 in itt.izip(container, col4):
            row.append(c4)
    if col5:
        for row, c5 in itt.izip(container, col5):
            row.append(c5)
```

I felt stuck between having to repeat my code, or having to iterate over the lists multiple times. As you can see above I seem to have ended up doing both. Any ideas of a better way to do this without iterating over the list multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just setting col4 and col5 to empty tuples by default, and then using `izip_longest`?

```
def csvContainer(col1, col2, col3, col4=(), col5=()):
    container = [
        [x for x in items if x is not None] for items in 
        itt.izip_longest(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
        ]
```

(The nested comprehension is just so you get `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, None, None]` when the extra columns are not present.)

This could also be generalized:

```
def csvContainer(*cols):
    container = [
        [x for x in items if x is not None] for items in 
        itt.izip_longest(*cols)
        ]
```